# Angular 4 call function inside service

Tags: angular, socket.io

I have `chat.service.ts` file. In this file, I have some functions. But I want to call a function inside constructor but I got an `ERROR TypeError: this.join is not a function`. I need help how to call a function inside service.

Here is my sample code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ChatService {
  private url = 'http://localhost:5000/';
  private socket;

  constructor() {
    this.socket = io(this.url, {
      "query": "token=XXXX"
    });

    this.socket.on('connect', function () {
      console.log("Connection Made.");
      this.join();
    });
  }

  public join(): void {
    this.socket.emit('join', {
      "login_token": "XXXX"
    });
  }

  public sendMessage(message) {
    this.socket.emit('message', message);
  }

  public getMessages = () => {
    return Observable.create((observer) => {
      this.socket.on('new-message', (message) => {
        observer.next(message);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using an arrow syntax `=>` instead to preserve the context of `this` to the class within the socket handler/callback:

```
this.socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log("Connection Made.");
  this.join();
});
```

Hopefully that helps!